# Python: Concatenation of two Lists behaving weird

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, and I wrote the below code which returns the kth row of a Pascal triangle where k is supplied as 'rowIndex' parameter. The problem occurs in the map function where the concatenation `[0]+row` is working fine but `row+[0]` is not working and an error is being thrown as shown below. This problem didn't occur in the code which is implemented using zip instead of map (which is commented out in the below code) Can anyone point out what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Error:

> row = [map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0]+row, row+[0])]
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def getRow(self, rowIndex):
        """
        :type rowIndex: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        row = [1]
        for _ in range(rowIndex):
            row = [map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0]+row, row+[0])]
            # row = [x + y for x, y in zip([0]+row, row+[0])]
        return row
obj = Solution()
print obj.getRow(3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` returns a list, you should not wrap it with `[...]`.

```
>>> map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0,1,2], [1,2,0])  # Python 2.x
[1, 3, 2]
```

By wrapping it with `[..]`, you will get a list of a list; which will cause `TypeError` after the first iteration:

```
>>> [map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0,1,2], [1,2,0])]
[[1, 3, 2]]
```

---

```
row = map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0]+row, row+[0])
```

If you are using Python 3.x, `map` returns an iterator; you need to convert it to list using `list` function to get a list object:

```
>>> map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0,1,2], [1,2,0])  # Python 3.x
<map object at 0x7f5acef0a0b8>
>>> list(map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0,1,2], [1,2,0]))
[1, 3, 2]
```

---

```
row = list(map(lambda a, b: a + b, [0]+row, row+[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. That helps a lot.